# How can i print the button name that trigger the event?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have made this program and I want to print a message and the name of the button, when I click some button. But it does not print anything and does not make any error.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Hello");
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea();
        HelloActionListener listen = new HelloActionListener(txtArea);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("TOP");
        b1.addActionListener(listen);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("LEFT");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("RIGHT");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("BOTTOM");
        b4.addActionListener(listen);
    }
}
```

And the class `HelloActionListener`:

```
public class HelloActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public JTextArea area;

    public HelloActionListener(JTextArea area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton x = (JButton) e.getSource();
        area.setText("Hello Folks" + x.getText());
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where my error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three main problems. The first one is that you aren't adding your `Button`s to the `Jpanel` you've created (`buttonsPanel`), nor are you adding the `buttonsPanel` to your `frame`, and you also aren't adding the `txtArea` to the `frame`. Second, your order of operations is off. I recommend calling the `frame.setVisible(true)` after you've finished building the frame. The third issue is you're using the `BorderLayout` on your `JFrame`, which is just not a very good layout to work with (in my opinion). Your listener and the other code all looks fine.

Changing your code to this seems to make it run as desired:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Hello");
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea("Place Holder");
    txtArea.setColumns(2);
    HelloActionListener listen = new HelloActionListener(txtArea);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("TOP");
    b1.addActionListener(listen);
    buttonsPanel.add(b1);
    JButton b2 = new JButton("LEFT");
    buttonsPanel.add(b2);
    JButton b3 = new JButton("RIGHT");
    buttonsPanel.add(b3);
    JButton b4 = new JButton("BOTTOM");
    b4.addActionListener(listen);
    buttonsPanel.add(b4);

    frame.add(txtArea);
    frame.add(buttonsPanel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I'd recommend reading [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) about layout managers in Java though. Even though it works here, this isn't a great way to have your layout.

Comment: `which is just not a very good layout to work with ` - BorderLayout is a good stating point for most frames. Typically you would add a  "toolbar" panel to the "NORTH" and a "status" panel to the "SOUTH" (if either is required). In the "CENTER" you add the main application components to another panel with the appropriate layout manager. This size of this area changes as the frame changes. I fail to see why you would use a GridLayout for the buttonsPanel and textarea. Why would the size of the two be the same? Typically the button panel would be fixed and the text area would grow/shrink.

Comment: @camickr - As you said, it is a good starting point. However, for full scale Java applications, I tend to shy away from `BorderLayout`. I prefer to use grid based layouts as they can give you more control over the positioning of items (even though I didn't really utilize this here - I was simply trying to devise a solution to OP's main question).

Comment: Even in a full scale application BorderLayout is a reasonable place to start. because you have a logical breadown of high level compnents. Look at most applications you have 1) a menu bar 2) toolbar 3) application area 4) status bar. So you use the areas of the BorderLayout for the high level breakdown. Then you use your "grid based layout" for the CENTER panel an its unique requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your time! With your advice I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `txtArea` to your frame.